# RavenDB on Restored AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ravendb, nservicebus5

I have a UAT ENVIRONMENT where I am using NServiceBUS endpoints. Everything works. Then when we moved to Production, the method we used to make the environment was to make an IMAGE of the UAT server and restore on a new AWS server instance

We reinstalled RAVENDB but on Windows authentication page in manage server, we are seeing the authentication from the old server. I have removed the RavenSITE folder and uninstalled RavenDB, restarted the server and tried installing again, but the old authentication line items are still coming up. Where are these getting stored? So I can go delete them.

The endpoints are also not registering with the instance and the databases are not getting created for each endpoint

Please assist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are stored in the System database.

Comment: Yes sir! they are in the system database and I have gotten rid of them.